# Compute standard error in the group difference in marginal effect

Tags: r, regression, marginal-effect

I am running a fixest effects regression of the following model.

$$Y_{it} = \beta_0 + X_{it}\beta_1 + T_{1it}\beta_2 +T_{2it}\beta_3 + X_{it}T_{1it}\beta_4 + X_{it}T_{2it}\beta_5 + \alpha_{it} + \epsilon_{it}$$

where, for simplicity, $Y_{it}$ is continuous while $X_{it}$ and $T_{jit}$ are categorical. (In fact, there are several $j$, but I have stuck with two for simplicity). The control group is the reference group. I would like to compute the following marginal effects using the `marginaleffects` package in R. The regression object is a `fixest` object generated by `feols`.

1. The difference in the the effect of $T_{1it}$ relative to the reference category across $X_{it}$
2. The difference in the the effect of $T_{2it}$ relative to the reference category across $X_{it}$

Are there any one-liners that let you do this using `marginaleffects`? So far, I have been trying the following:

```
comparisons(regression_model, 
                       variables = "treatment", 
                              by = "X", 
                      hypothesis = "sequential")
```

which generates what I need, but also many extraneous comparisons like $T_2$ when $X=1$ less $T_1$ when $X=0$. Normally, this would not be a problem, but I am working with a massive dataset where such comparisons take hours. The use of "sequential" followed by selection of the hypotheses I want works, but generates too many comparisons.

Surprisingly, the code:

```
comparisons(regression_model, 
                       variables = "treatment", 
                              by = "X")
```

generates two rows, but does not difference them and construct an appropriate standard error. It also generates too many comparisons when the treatment variable is a factor with more than 2 values. I also tried

```
comparisons(regression_model, 
                       variables = "treatment", 
                              by = "X", hypothesis = "reference")
```

which generates contrasts all possible comparisons with the reference treatment and $X_{it} = 0$, which is also undesirable. Any recommendations or alternative packages that work with for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `variables` argument accepts shortcuts like `"sequential"`, but also vectors of length two with the actual levels you want to compare. Please read the documentation, as this is clearly explained.

Also, the `hypothesis` argument is a very flexible mechanism to compare the estimates in different rows of the output produced by any function in the `marginaleffects` package.

In this example  model, the reference category for `gear` is 4, the level of interest is 5, and we treat the variable as a factor. The grouping variable is `cyl`:

```r
library(marginaleffects)

dat <- transform(mtcars, gear = factor(gear))
mod <- lm(mpg ~ cyl * gear, data = dat)
```

This gives us 3 average comparisons:

```r
comparisons(mod,
    variables = list(gear = c("4", "5")),
    by = "cyl")
# 
#  Term          Contrast cyl Estimate Std. Error     z Pr(>|z|)   S 2.5 % 97.5 %
#  gear mean(5) - mean(4)   6    1.630       2.18 0.747    0.455 1.1 -2.65   5.91
#  gear mean(5) - mean(4)   4    0.855       2.47 0.346    0.729 0.5 -3.98   5.69
#  gear mean(5) - mean(4)   8    2.405       4.08 0.589    0.556 0.8 -5.60  10.41
# 
# Columns: term, contrast, cyl, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted, predicted_hi, predicted_lo
```

Now, suppose we can compare the 1st and the 3rd one. Just use the `hypothesis` argument:

```r
comparisons(mod,
    variables = list(gear = c("4", "5")),
    by = "cyl",
    hypothesis = "b1 = b3")
# 
#   Term Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)   S 2.5 % 97.5 %
#  b1=b3   -0.775       2.57 -0.301    0.763 0.4 -5.82   4.27
# 
# Columns: term, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high
```

Edit:

The development version of the package (0.16.0) supports multiple entries in `hypothesis=c("b1=b3", "b2=b3")`

Comment: Thank you. I would like to compare many treatments to a specific baseline by a covariate. For instance, does studying regime T1 increase sex differences on a test compared to a placebo? Does studying regime T2, T3 increase sex differences... etc. My apologies for being unclear - but I am familiar with the single comparison you have outlined; it is indeed explained well in the documentation. The option "sequential" essentially generates twice as many hypotheses as I need and I have to filter down. I don't see how to specify exactly the hypotheses easily using the "hypothesis" option.

Comment: The edited answer solves my problem and I have approved it as the final answer. Thank you.